# Wordpress plugin "Download Manager" download button text change to icon

Tags: wordpress

I'm using WPDM plugin for Wordpress website. When displaying packages, I want to change "Download" button text to only icon.

The problem is that in package settings I can only change button text and it does not accept HTML input, so I cannot write something like:`<i class="fa fa-download"></i>`.

I found a code snippet on internet which should allow to write HTML in button label field:

```
function wpdm_html_link_label($data, $ID){
    $data['link_label'] = get_post_meta($ID, '__wpdm_link_label', true );
    return $data;
}
add_filter('wpdm_custom_data','wpdm_html_link_label', 10, 2);
```

But it seems to not be working.

Any ideas?